# Django's adding parentheses itself to the model name in the admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-models

I don't know why this is happening to my website.. As my perspective, I'm doing all these things right. But there should be something which hid from my eyes.

Here is a screenshot of the current result:
[image]

And here is my models.py and admin.py files.

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.dispatch import receiver

from . import managers


class Profile(models.Model):
    # Relations
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='profile',
        verbose_name=_('user'),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    # Attributes - Mandatory
    interaction = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        default=0,
        verbose_name=_('interaction')
    )


    # Custom Properties
    @property
    def username(self):
        return self.user.username

    # Methods

    # Meta and String
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Profile"),
        verbose_name_plural = _("Profiles"),
        ordering = ('user',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


@receiver(models.signals.post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_profile_for_new_user(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        profile = Profile(user=kwargs['instance'])
        profile.save()
```

**admin.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from . import models


@admin.register(models.Profile)
class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['username', 'interaction']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hte comma after the declarations...  Example:

```
>>> a = ("SAFDFD"),
>>> _
>>> ("SAFDFD",)
```

Comment: Omg. I'm feeling stupid right now. They're not in a list, for sure. Thanks.